# How to make an application to run in portrait mode only

Tags: android

In my application If i want to restrict an activity to work in portrait mode only then i have to write `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in the manifest file against activity tag. If I want to force all activity to work in portrait mode then I have to write the same in all activity. Is there any application-wise setting so that I need not have to write this in all activities. How to make an application to run in portrait mode only

### I am using the following now

```
        <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name=".MyActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" is not needed to force orientation I think. android:screenOrientation="portrait" should be enough

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Only way is to add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` for each activity.

Comment: can u share if you know any other method.
I am having problem with the Facebook login in my app.

Answer (score 10):

I'm afraid that I can't answer your question but I need to write a response anyway.

I'm sure that you're writing the greatest app ever and that there is some awesome reason why it should be locked to portrait mode only.  But have you considered phones with slide-out keyboards?  If your app involves text entry then anyone with a full qwerty keyboard phone (e.g. Droid/Milestone 1/2, G1, etc) is going to be rotating their phone, sliding out the keyboard and discovering to their horror that the app hasn't rotated with them.

Something to think about.  Good luck with your problem and with your app!

Comment: Although not answering the question, it is relevant and good thinking

Comment: I'm glad that you agree.  I use a hardware keyboard Android phone and apps that don't rotate when I use the keyboard are /really annoying/.

Comment: Ok, So what if I am developing an application which will run only on a particular handset and I know for sure it doesn't have a physical handset.

Comment: Then I guess you don't need to worry about it?

Comment: should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Not answering the question

Comment: [Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#In_popular_culture) @USER_NAME.  Sometimes "don't do that" is the right response.  Given the evolution of Android handsets, this answer is less relevant now, but back in 2011 this was a very relevant UX point to make.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to set application-wide orientation. But there is one interesting value called [`behind`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen):

```
android:screenOrientation="behind"
```

But you still need to apply it for each activity. So its better to just stick with `portrait` in your case.

Also note that you need to have very good reasons to restrict orientation in your app. In general this is considered a bad practice and may frustrate quite a lot of users.

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity android:name=".exampleActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

HI use  this code `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` 
I don't think that there would be another way for this type reuirement

Answer (score 0):

You can support Landscape mode on activity that involve text entry where using a physical keyboard might be required and keeping the rest of your app in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

**Recommended way is to use the tag for all activities in manifest**.
But, if any1 wants laziest approach you can use following code.

In onCreate() of your Application class, include the following code.

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

use these line inside your application tag.

it may help you or use this line android:screenOrientation="portrait" with each activity.

Comment: this will not work...because there's no screenOrientation property for application tag